# jQuery UI vs Telerik vs ...?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, controls, telerik

I'm in the process of building a web cms platform. And I've come to a point where I have to choose what actually goes in the pages (I've been building the "core" for now).

What do you think is the best option and could you give me your reasons for choosing that?

Currently I'm looking at [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com), and I'm also juggling with the idea of just building controls by myself, but I think that's too much of a hassle for little gain...

I'd love to hear your opinions, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built my own CMS solely on the Telerik ASP.NET Ajax tools.  It's really good, and if you're careful, performance will be comparable to jQuery-UI.  If you're just doing it for "one client at a time", why not grab a copy of [SiteFinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/) and include the licensing cost in the overall price?

jQuery has some really great tools too, but I prefer the simple nature of the Telerik tools.

Comment: FYI, the Vancouver International Airport ( [YVR](http://www.yvr.ca/en/Default.aspx) ) is built using SiteFinity.

Comment: Agreed.  Just grab Sitefinity.  Building a basic CMS is easy.  Building a mature CMS is hard.  Let others invent the wheel and build on top of their work.  Sitefinity can be extended using traditional ASP.NET controls.